# How to remove html tags and caption id and vc code from content in api in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, api, shortcode

I want to remove the html tags and the shortcode written in content posts in wordpress.

```
"content"=>strip_tags(strip_shortcodes($post->post_content));
```

i have tried this.

In the content there should be no html tags, caption id etc.
Can someone please help with this ?

Answer (score 0):

I did same a few days back but in WooCommerce page not in Posts and it worked for me. This is what I did.

Get the class of element you want to remove using Inspect functionality of browsers. Then add below code in Dashboard > Appearence > Customize > CustomCSS

```
.class_of_element_you_want_removed{
display:none;
}
```

You might have to try some hit and trial in getting the exact class name to remove the element from screen.

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Thank you. I did it with preg_replace as I din,t have to change the content bt this should not be visible in andriod app.

Comment: Are you referring to Web App that WordPress offers or a particular Android app on Play Store ?

Comment: No, actually I am building an app which is already a website in wordpress. so i was making an api in wordpress and getting posts content which incled html tags etc..